# Linking failure. How to use 'NtQuerySystemTime' windows function?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, time

I try this simple code to calculate HDD write speed in my application:

```
#include <winternl.h>

...
float speed;
double divident;
PLARGE_INTEGER systime0, systime1;
LONGLONG elapsed_time;
...

write_flag = true ;

NtQuerySystemTime(systime0) ;

f_out->write(out_buffer0, chunk_len0);
f_out->write(out_buffer1, chunk_len1);

NtQuerySystemTime(systime1);

elapsed_time = systime1->QuadPart - systime0->QuadPart;

write_flag = false ;

divident = static_cast<double>(chunk_len0 + chunk_len1) / 1.048576 ;  // 1.024 * 1.024 = 1.048576; divident yield value 1000000 times greater then value in MB
divident *= 10 ;  // I want 'speed' to be in MB/s
speed = divident / static_cast<double>(elapsed_time) ;
...
```

but it fails to link.

On MSDN, the [`NtQuerySystemTime` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724512.aspx) says there is no associated import library and that I must use the `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` functions to dynamically link to `Ntdll.dll`. But I don't understand how to use those functions. Can someone please provide a code example of how to use those functions?

Comment: That same article also says: "Applications should use the `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` function". So why don't you? What do you feel `NtQuerySystemTime` gives you that you can't obtain otherwise?

Comment: Well, maybe I should read more carefully, but an answer to my question explaining how to use `NtQuerySystemTime()` is also good for me as I will learn more

Comment: There is no reason to use NtQuerySystemTime since GetSystemTimeAsFileTime does the same thing and will be supported in future versions of Windows. Make sure your customers understand that your program relies on a function that is explicitly documented as "may stop working at any time" so that when it stops working, they will call you instead of Microsoft.

Comment: Thank You for advise. I didn't know that it may not be supported in the future. I'm writing almost everything for myself yet, but the it may change. I moddified my program and it use `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` now.

Comment: First sentence on the [NtQuerySystemTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724512.aspx) documentation page (the one you linked to): *"NtQuerySystemTime may be altered or unavailable in future versions of Windows."* [It has been there in 2012 already](https://web.archive.org/web/20121109204330/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724512(v=vs.85).aspx). That's pretty darn impossible to miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would be able to use this function.

```
HMODULE hNtDll = GetModuleHandleA("ntdll");
NTSTATUS (WINAPI *NtQuerySystemTime)(PLARGE_INTEGER) = 
    (NTSTATUS (WINAPI*)(PLARGE_INTEGER))GetProcAddress(hNtDll, "NtQuerySystemTime");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef  NTSYSAPI (CALLBACK *LPNTQUERYSYSTEMTIME)(PLARGE_INTEGER);

void main(void)
{
    PLARGE_INTEGER  SystemTime;
    SystemTime = (PLARGE_INTEGER) malloc(sizeof(LARGE_INTEGER));

    HMODULE hNtDll = GetModuleHandleA("ntdll");

    LPNTQUERYSYSTEMTIME fnNtQuerySystemTime = (LPNTQUERYSYSTEMTIME)GetProcAddress(hNtDll, "NtQuerySystemTime");

    if(fnNtQuerySystemTime){

        printf("found NtQuerySystemTime function at ntdll.dll address:%p\n",fnNtQuerySystemTime);
        fnNtQuerySystemTime(SystemTime);
        printf("%llx\n", SystemTime->QuadPart);

    }

    free(SystemTime);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `malloc()` and `free()` in C++, use `new` and `delete` instead (or better, a smart pointer like `std::auto_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`). In this case, I wouldn't dynamically allocate  `SystemTime` at all, I would declare it on the stack instead and then use the `&` operator to pass it to `NtQuerySystemTime()`, eg: `LARGE_INTEGER SystemTime; ... fnNtQuerySystemTime(&SystemTime); printf("%llx\n", SystemTime.QuadPart); ...`

Comment: @RemyLebeau i'm learnning ansi c recently and wrote this code in Visual C++6,did not know C++,i've been tryed you advice,it raise an error:error C2664: 'int (union _LARGE_INTEGER *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'union _LARGE_INTEGER ** ' to 'union _LARGE_INTEGER *'

Comment: the question is tagged C++. And if you are getting an error then you are doing something wrong.